# How to authenticate with git?

Tags: ssh, git, login, webserver, authentication

I have been provided with connection details to a git server:
`http://hgk:hgk_499@git.server1.org/clients/app_server1.git`

I have downloaded a git client and after entering the server as: `http://git.server1.org`, I get a request for user credentials to which I enter for user: `hgk` and password: `hgk_499`. It fails with an authentication error, however I have no problem cloning using:

> git clone http://hgk:hgk_499@git.server1.org/clients/app_server1.git

What did I do wrong and what is the correct way to authenticate to git?

Comment: What git client do you use? I guess it's something on Windows?

Comment: No, not windows and I use SmartGit.